# authentication error for GEMALTO SIM "6982-Security status not satisfied"

Tags: java, command, apdu, sim-card

I am trying to access data stored in SIM card (Citizen identity card) by using smart card reader. So here is what i've did:

- Selected MF by: **A0 A4 00 00 02 3F 00** with successful response of **90 00**
- Selected DF/EF by: **A0 A4 00 00 02 3F 01** with successful response of **90 00**

After these i should send READ BINARY command by **00 B0 00 00 0A** but it gets response of "**6982:Security status not satisfied**".

How do i satisfy this security status? Or am i selecting wrong files?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the specification and use CLA as 0xA0.

Comment: Let me know about the sim card specification.

Comment: When talking about SIM Cards, you need to refer to 3GPP specification for APDU commands instead of ISO 7816. Please note that the CLA byte is proprietary, i.e. using 0xA0.

Try to send SELECT APDU command, with MF as the file identifier, as follow:
A0 A4 00 00 02 3F 00
You should get 9FXX response.